# Write elasticsearch data in json file

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have 3 node elasticsearch cluster and I put data in index name pp_index in json format. I want to read that data and write in json file.

I can read data from below command but how can I write that data in json file

```
   curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET http://localhost:9200/pp_index/_search?pretty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl `-o` parameter to write output to the file like below:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X GET http://localhost:9200/pp_index/_search?pretty -o myfile.json
```

But above search API will return only top 10 document from your index as you are not passing `size` param. If you need more data you can set `size` param value and it support max `10000`.

```
http://localhost:9200/pp_index/_search?size=10000
```

I will suggest to use Java or Python elasticsearch client as you can get all the data from index and export it using client.